# XSLT copy elements from one file to another matching two conditions

Tags: xml, xslt, copy, key, match

pretty basic question here.
I am trying to write an XSLT to copy over elements (`<w>`) into a file (from another file) if the `<w>`s match on two parameters:

- `@lemma` must match in both elements and
- `text()` must match for the
  first `<m>` element of the target and the full `<w>` in the source
  (even if it is across several `<m>`s.

If either parameter doesn't match, then the `<w>` should remain unmodified.

Here is a sample file to be modified.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <text>
    <w lemma="FishCake" corresp="1"><m baseForm="FishCake">FishCake</m></w>
    <w lemma="FishCake" corresp="1"><m baseForm="FishCake">FishCake</m><m baseForm="FishCake">FishCake</m></w>
    <w lemma="FishCake" corresp="1"><m baseForm="FishCake">FishCake</m><m baseForm="s">s</m></w>
    <w lemma="FishCake" corresp="1"><m baseForm="FishC">FishC</m><m baseForm="ake">ake</m></w>
    <w lemma="cat" corresp="1"><m baseForm="dog">dog</m></w>
    <w lemma="dog" corresp="1"><m baseForm="cat">cat</m></w>
    <w lemma="dog" corresp="1"><m baseForm="dog">dog</m></w> 
    <w lemma="dog" corresp="1"><m baseForm="dog">dog</m><m baseForm="cat">cat</m></w>
   </text>
```

Here is a sample file with elements to be copied over (source.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <text>
                <w lemma="FishCake" corresp="2"><m baseForm="Fish">Fish</m><m baseForm="Cake">Cake</m></w>
                <w lemma="dog" corresp="2"><m baseForm="dog">dog</m></w>
    </text>
```

I would expect the code to produce:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <text>
                   <w lemma="FishCake" corresp="2"><m baseForm="Fish">Fish</m><m baseForm="Cake">Cake</m></w>
                   <w lemma="FishCake" corresp="2"><m baseForm="Fish">Fish</m><m baseForm="Cake">Cake</m></w>
                   <w lemma="FishCake" corresp="1"><m baseForm="FishCake">FishCake</m><m baseForm="s">s</m></w>
                   <w lemma="FishCake" corresp="1"><m baseForm="FishC">FishC</m><m baseForm="ake">ake</m></w>
                   <w lemma="cat" corresp="1"><m baseForm="dog">dog</m></w>
                   <w lemma="dog" corresp="1"><m baseForm="cat">cat</m></w>
                   <w lemma="dog" corresp="2"><m baseForm="dog">dog</m></w>
                   <w lemma="dog" corresp="2"><m baseForm="dog">dog</m></w>
       </text>
```

I've tried the following XSLT (a lousy attempt at modifying some code I had already), but only manage to get it to match on the `@lemma`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xpath-default-namespace="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">
    <xsl:param name="lookup-doc" select="document('source.xml')"/>
    <xsl:key name="ref" match="*[@lemma|m[1]/text()]" use="@lemma|m[1]/text()"/>  
 <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
    <xsl:mode name="ref-copy" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
    <xsl:template match="*[key('ref', @lemma|m[1]/text(), $lookup-doc)]">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('ref', @lemma|m[1]/text(), $lookup-doc)" mode="ref-copy">
          
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

what I get is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><text>
    <w lemma="FishCake" corresp="2"><m baseForm="Fish">Fish</m><m baseForm="Cake">Cake</m></w>
    <w lemma="FishCake" corresp="2"><m baseForm="Fish">Fish</m><m baseForm="Cake">Cake</m></w>
    <w lemma="FishCake" corresp="2"><m baseForm="Fish">Fish</m><m baseForm="Cake">Cake</m></w>
    <w lemma="FishCake" corresp="2"><m baseForm="Fish">Fish</m><m baseForm="Cake">Cake</m></w>
    <w lemma="cat" corresp="1"><m baseForm="dog">dog</m></w>
    <w lemma="dog" corresp="2"><m baseForm="dog">dog</m></w>
    <w lemma="dog" corresp="2"><m baseForm="dog">dog</m></w> 
    <w lemma="dog" corresp="2"><m baseForm="dog">dog</m></w>
   </text>
```

Any tips? Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't been able to full grasp the rules and an attempt to write them as a key and use that

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:param name="doc2">
     <text>
                <w lemma="FishCake" corresp="2"><m baseForm="Fish">Fish</m><m baseForm="Cake">Cake</m></w>
                <w lemma="dog" corresp="2"><m baseForm="dog">dog</m></w>
    </text>      
  </xsl:param>
  
  <xsl:key name="ref" match="w" composite="yes" use="@lemma, ."/>
  
  <xsl:template match="w[key('ref', (@lemma, m[1]), $doc2)]">
      <xsl:copy-of select="key('ref', (@lemma, m[1]), $doc2)"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

does not quite give the result you have described (the second document is inline for compactness and completeness of the example but of course it could use `<xsl:param name="doc2" select="doc($lookup-doc)"/>` instead).

Perhaps you can clarify which document is the "source", which the "target" and explain the rules in a bit more detail and also why the examples given match or don't match.

Comment: Hi Martin. Thanks so much – this is exactly what I was struggling with – basically the parentheses for the matching and a general lack of XSLT background.
Indeed, I can see how I confused you there – I got my target and source muddled up in my response. The fourth example should have been a match, as your code predicts.